# Renderer stops working when inserting specific code into function! three.js

Tags: variables, three.js, geometry

I would like to start off by mentioning that I am very new to coding, so some things that might seem very simple to someone with intermediate experience will probably not click quite as fast with me.

Okay so with the code I am writing, I am trying to get a three.js cube object to move to the places I click, using tweening. I managed to get this to work, but when I try to create a frame using three.js lines, the code stops working. In detail: when I add

```
line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial() );

scene.addObject( line );
```

to the Init() function. What is cause of this? My guess is it has something to do with global/local variables but even if that were correct I have no idea how to fix it !

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sawura/FjKZP/24/) for reference

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but your code on JSFiddle is quite messed up. It loads three.js three times by specifying: (1) Three.js r54 (an old version) as a library, (2) a copy of three.js r54 (the same old version) as an external resource, and (3) a copy of three.js r44 (a very, very old version) as an external resource. In addition, your `init()` function contains an erroneous line `onDocumentMouseDown( event );`.

Comment: Hi @YuAsakusa! Yeah, that does seem unnecessary. I have changed it to only use the r54 as a library by removing the extensions. I can't seem to find r66 (the newest) anywhere but on GitHub, however. 

I thought I was calling the function using onDocumentMouseMove, but it seems to run just the same without it, which is what I think you mean. 

The problem persists however, you can still click the screen to get the mouse coordinates - but nothing is rendered. I found this on the changes page under r59: "Added WebGLRenderer support for LinePieces with BufferGeometry". Could this be the culprit?

Comment: You should first check the “getting started” page and examples on threejs.org to understand how to use three.js. `THREE.Camera` must be changed to `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`. Three.js r66 is available from http://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/r66/build/three.js, although this relies on rawgithub.com (not raw.github.com). Moreover, the line `onDocumentMouseDown( event );` is not just unnecessary but it is incorrect. It refers to undefined variable `event`, and the execution stops right at that point.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now, don't know how I missed the camera. I also removed 'event' from within the function's brackets. I will update the fiddle in my original question if you want to have a look!